'UserControl' is a namespace but is used like a type
this is the code for my CardDay.xaml where i designed the card view for my weather app using WPF framework in which i'm very new and learning
<UserControl x:Class="WeatherApp.UserControl.CardDay"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Name="cardDay">
    <Border CornerRadius="10" Width="85" Padding="10" Margin="0 0 10 0" BorderThickness="1">
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#e9e9e9e9"/>

                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#03a9f4"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Day, ElementName=cardDay}" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Source, ElementName=cardDay}" Width="30" Margin="0 10 0 10"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MaxNum, ElementName=cardDay}" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiBold" Margin="0 0 8 0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MinNum, ElementName=cardDay}" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiBold" Background="#7a7a7a"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</UserControl>

and here is the code for CardDay.xaml.cs which i guess work as backend code for my weather app. really don't know much about C# and i'm learning and this is my first time using this language for a project.

using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WeatherApp.UserControl
{

    public partial class CardDay : UserControl
    {
        public CardDay()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public string Day
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(DayProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DayProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DayProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Day", typeof(string), typeof(CardDay));



        public string MaxNum
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(MaxNumProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MaxNumProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxNumProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MaxNum", typeof(string), typeof(CardDay));


        public string MinNum
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(MinNumProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MinNumProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MinNumProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MinNum", typeof(string), typeof(CardDay));


        public ImageSource Source
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(CardDay));
    }
}


where you'll be able to see the UserControl is red underlined and not working in any other way.
public partial class CardDay : UserControl
{
    public CardDay()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

CardDay: UserControl is showing used as a type
how can i solve it ??
really new at this thing
Tried to use the potential fixes but it didn't work.

It was not a terribly good idea to name your namespace UserControl.. If you want to keep the name, you will have to write System.Windows.Controls.UserControl as base class instead of simply UserControl.

A side note: if this is the first time you use C# you might consider to start with a simpler hello-world application.

Call your namespace WeatherApp.UserControls (with a plural "s") to resolve the conflict the WPF UserControl.

The issue should be obvious. Look at your own code:
namespace WeatherApp.UserControl

You have literally called your namespace UserControl. You can't then use the name UserControl in your code and expect it to be interpreted as something else. One option would be to fully qualify the type name when you use it, e.g.
public partial class CardDay : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl

but that's a bad idea. The appropriate course of action is to not name your namespace so badly in the first place. I'm not sure what might be more appropriate because I don't know what else it's supposed to contain but one option might be this:
namespace WeatherApp.CardDayUserControl

Try to name things descriptively and in such a way as to avoid name clashes.
